# Google API | Distance Matrix

Tags: google-api, google-distancematrix-api

I need help with my code.

First, is my approach correct that I use the GoogleDistanceMatrix to get the real route distance and not just the linear distance?

I want to use an Geocoordinate for the origin and destination Adress but it doesnt seem to work:

```
public double CalculateGoogleDistance(GeoCoordinate from, GeoCoordinate to) {
  DistanceMatrixRequest request = new DistanceMatrixRequest();
  request.Key = "****";

  request.Origins = new Location[] {
    new Location(from)
  };
  request.Destinations = new Location[] {
    new Location(to)
  };

  var response = GoogleApi.GoogleMaps.DistanceMatrix.Query(request);

  return response.Rows.First().Elements.First().Distance.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you appear to be using 3rd party libraries/repositories in using Google Maps API services, so I would advice that you only follow their official documentations, in which I will be providing as I answer your questions.

As mentioned in their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests), even though it is optional, the default `trafic_model` is `bestguess`, meaning that the result will be based on the best estimate of travel time given what is known about **both historical traffic conditions and live traffic**. You can learn more about the other traffic model optional parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#DrivingOptions).

Now, with regards to getting "real route distance", you are only referring to the *live* result excluding historical traffic. To get this, you would need to specify the `departureTime` to now as given in the example from the doc:

```
drivingOptions: {
    departureTime: new Date(Date.now() + N),  // for the time N milliseconds from now.
    trafficModel: 'bestguess'
}
```

As you can see, that is how Distance Matrix API works.

> Note: The departure time and traffic model is also applicable to Directions API.

See this link for the web service version of [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview) web service.